# How many files can be uploaded to a Document Library at a time?

Tags: document-library

How many files can be uploaded to a Document Library at a time?

Answer (score 1):

It depends which 'uploader' you are using. Microsoft has changed this at some stage with a service pack.

The 'drag and drop' uploader maxes out at 100 files (without giving a decent message). The 'Treeview' based uploader does not have a limit I believe, but has other annoying limitations.

Answer (score 1):

it also depends if you are uploading manually, or through another program (api)

Answer (score -1):

Depend on Web application that you set **Maximum Upload Size**. You can find this settings at **Central Administration** > **Application Management** > **Web Application** > **General Settings** > **General Settings**.

Comment: I don't think he was asking about the size, just the number of files.